# Should this question be a community wiki or not?

Tags: discussion, questions, community-wiki

On the recent question [How to help a teenager that doesn't want to change in a school locker room?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/21646/how-to-help-a-teenager-that-doesnt-want-to-change-in-a-school-locker-room), the OP requested that it be converted to a community wiki. The logic behind the request is that different underlying causes for not wanting to change in front of peers (religious restriction, anxiety, physical impairment), and the appropriate accommodation of that concern may be different in each case.

**Should this question be a community wiki?** Why or why not?

Related reading:

- [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) (StackExchange FAQ)
- [The Future of Community Wiki](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/) (StackExchange blog post, 2011)

Comment: Thanks for posting the meta Q!

Comment: Not sure if it's covered in those 2 links explicitly, but the hard rule on the whole network is that CW is NOT a proper way to treat questions that shouldn't be open (e.g. too broad, as the example given seems to imply). There were numerous statements to that effect that I saw, from SHog9 and some other SE community team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it should be Community Wiki.

First off, the question as asked right now has reasonable answer(s).  It is asked as a "belief", and that means it's the first of the causes (give or take).

Second, Community Wiki isn't intended as a fix for a "too broad" question.  That's what's being suggested here: the question has multiple correct answers, right?  That's not the point of CW.  In fact, as Grace notes in the "Future" post linked above,

> questions rarely, if ever, need community wiki.

Perhaps a specific answer might justify it - but I don't think that applies here, either.  This is neither such a difficult or complex question, nor is it a question with a 'list' element that is expected to be collaborative.  It might have multiple approaches based on the root cause, but either they're similar enough that answers can include the main root causes, or the causes are sufficintly different that separate questions are appropriate.

---

I think that, for the specific question at hand, the differences between the root causes - religious belief, anxiety, physical disability - are not going to factor significantly in the answers.  The only significant difference is whether the school *must* make an accommodation; that's a minor element of the answer, in my opinion.  The other things - how to get the school to cooperate, how to deal with kids teasing, etc. - all are ultimately the same, or similar enough, in my opinion.